# Loading sql tables to an xml file using Talend with schema defined at runtime

Tags: sql, xml, talend

I'm a bigginner at Talend,and I'm trying to load a database into an XML file, and that must be  done automatically.So I don't have to specify any schema for the xml file all must be generated, because I'll have to use that XML file in other jobs. Is that possible using Talend ? and how can I do it ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It's possible, but the question is too vague, you should define your needs better. Do you need to load one or multiple tables? Which is the input schema? And the XML structure schema? How do you mean with "automatically" and in which kind of job you need to use the output XML also? Are they Talend job or something else?

Comment: Actually, I have some jobs that take for input an XML file. Now I want to work with databases, so I'll have to convert my data base into  XML files so that I can work with my jobs. Of course I want to do this using a Talend job, but I don't know the schema of the xml file it must be detected from the data base schema.

Comment: This is not possible by the very inner design of Talend: every schema (db, xml, delimited-files...) must be defined at compile time. It's not possible to detect it at runtime. If it's your case, you would probably have to redesign your process, I'm afraid

Comment: you welcome :) I moved the notApplicable comment to answer, then changed the title for better reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible by the very inner design of Talend: every schema (db, xml, delimited-files...) must be defined at compile time. It's not possible to detect it at runtime. You *could* try a complete java-solution using a [user routine](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Creating+a+user+routine) and some custom code, but this will move to a complete java-based solution, outside from Talend scope (and very inelegant and time-consuming, in my opinion). If it's your case, you probably should redesign your process.